# Print file of unknown encoding without discovering the encoding

Tags: python

I have a binary file where 99% of the characters are standard ascii and the 1% could be absolutely anything (including zero) so I don't think it conforms to any standard encoding. I would like to print the contents of this file to screen and I don't mind how the odd characters appear. Is there any such thing as a function like:

```
string = any_old_junk_binary_to_string(binary)
```

which will perhaps replace characters it doesn't like with some generic marker character or even or even omit that character?

Comment: A binary file doesn't follow any encoding. Do you want to print the bytes in it?

Comment: I want to see the alphabetic characters where possible. So if one of the bytes is 65 then I would like to see "A" if the byte was something unprintable like 0 then I don't care what is shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. You can use the `errors` argument to decode, like this:

```
string = binary.decode('ASCII', errors="replace")
```

This will replace any invalid bytes with �. There are other options available depending what you want to do with invalid characters, see [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) for a full list.